# Unable to SSH using Bash on WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have recently installed Bash on Windows thru WSL.

However, when I tried to access my school server using SSH for my projects (as I normally would using PuTTY), I keep getting the following error message whenever I tried to SSH into my school network:

The command I entered was:

```
ssh username@schooldomain.edu.com
```

And the error message I received was:

```
Could not resolve hostname schooldomain.edu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

As I am rather new to unix system, I might have missed out certain configuration steps. That said, I could access my school's server using PuTTY. Please advice if there are any other configurations that I might have to do to get it working.

Thanks folks!

Comment: can you ping `schooldomain.edu.com`? Does `schooldomain.edu.com` exist?

Comment: Nope. I am unable to ping schooldomain.edu.com. The return was unknown host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like DNS issue. Make sure that you are able to ping schooldomain.edu.com as @ifconfig mentioned in the comment. Also make sure that you have the correct DNS entry in /etc/resolv.conf. It should look similar to

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I am using google DNS but you can use any DNS you want.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply. However, I am unable to ping to schooldomain.edu.com. I get ping: unknown host schooldomain.edu.com

I managed to get reply when I executed the ping command on my cmd (outside the unix environment) though. 

I have made changes to my resolv.conf like you mentioned but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you get access to the site using Windows on the same host? If so, did you have to make any Windows-specific configuration changes to do so?

Comment: Turns out that it was because AVG’s firewall blocks all WSL processes by default. Got it working finally. Thanks folks!